# Is there a way to get total spend & total sales on campaign using Amazon Advertising API?

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

Using Amazon Advertising api for campaign report what I am getting is attributed sales or a cost for provided date, how to retrieve total spend and total sales for the campaign.

Comment: did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

yes. need to do a report. Is easy.

//https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/reference/migration-guides/reporting-v2-v3
//https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/guides/reporting/v3/get-started
//https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/guides/reporting/v3/report-types/advertised-product
//https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/guides/reporting/v2/report-types